# How to resize the open-source to-do list system "MyTinyToDo"?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to include the open-source to-do list system called [MyTinyToDo](http://www.mytinytodo.net) on my website. When I resized it to be fit to the website layout, the position of the windows for some functions such as (Tags or arrow besides Tasks) of the system were changed and they messed the style.

By using the Firebug, I could be able to figure the reason of that problem. The reason is: this system uses JQuery to determine the position of those windows. I tried to find the statements that are responsible for this task inside the JQuery files but I failed to find them.

So what should I do?

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the "messed style"?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you include mytinytodo into an <iframe> ?
I gess it would prevent jQuery from bothering your layout.

Answer (score 0):

How you included the mytinytodo.net in your site.you have also included jquery in your website.Then may be jquery libraries may get clashed. Check out